# Sqlite3: Error deleting record: foreign key mismatch

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I am trying to delete a record from table users.

Tried deleteing it with a DELETE-statement (DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=10" as well as in my DB browser, but I get the above error, specifically it says: "Error deleting record: foreign key mismatch - "games" referencing "groups" (DELETE FROM "main"."users" WHERE *rowid* IN ('10');)".
Below my schema:

CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    hash VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(name));

CREATE TABLE 'groups' (
    'group_name' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    'turn' INTEGER NOT NULL,
    'user_id'INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY ('user_id') REFERENCES 'users'('user_id')
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE games (
    game_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    active INTEGER,
    turn INTEGER,
    group_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (turn) REFERENCES groups(turn_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (group_name) REFERENCES groups(group_name)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

Why is this a problem? user_id is not even a foreign key in 'games'?? Thank you!

Comment: Deleting the user cascades to deleting matching rows of groups which causes matching rows of games to... do nothing, causing a FK mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the end was my DB Browser for SQLite (3.11.2) whose GUI allows deletions but they don't actually work. When I tied again in the bash and closed and restarted the DB Browser, the rows were gone. Uninsightful but figured I'd post nonetheless in case anyone else comes across this.